# Exception creating EJB object

Tags: java, netbeans, ejb, runtime-error

I have a session bean that named ManagerBean and i have a application client that called Main which calls the session bean. The managerBean is used to receive a string for the session bean and sends the string back to a message driven bean in another project.

I can successfully run my ejb-module, which consists of my session bean, but when i run my application client, it gives an exception creating ejb object. Any advice on that?

```
 WARNING: EJB5059: Exception creating ejb object  : [ManagerBean]
 WARNING: create object exception
```

My session bean:

```
public class ManagerBean implements ManagerBeanRemote {

public ManagerBean() {
  }
 }
```

My application client:

```
public class Main {
@EJB
private static SuggestionManagerBeanRemote SSS;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public Main() {
 }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. There should be more in the error log. Show more of your code, too. One thing that does not seem correct - your session bean implements ManagerBeanRemote, but then you inject SuggestionManagerBeanRemote.

Comment: Is the session bean annotated ?